# Edittext in Android not being full size

Tags: android, textbox

So I have a edittext in Android.

Here is the declaration:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Type in here!"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:backgroundTint="#ffffffff"
    android:autoText="false" />
```

However I can only type text in the lower half of the textbox:

As you can see in the following image the prompt text appears 1/2 way down the textbox:

[image]

And I can only type text 1/2 way down the textbox:

[image]

Why is am I only allowed to type in 1/2 of my textbox even though in the design view it shows that the textbox is covering the entire screen.

Comment: Try setting `layout_height` as `match_parent`.

Comment: @siris_cac Changing it did not do anything. After I changed it i rebuilt the project to make sure it was updating but nothing happened.

Comment: Where do you want to type?

Comment: maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503668/multiline-edittext-in-android-with-the-cursor-starting-on-top) can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be easy, simply add the line:

```
android:gravity="top|left
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code edittext.

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"  
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: That doesn't work either all it does is make the textbox really small and move it to the upper left corner.

Comment: Ooops I messed up your changes a little bit (I deleted some extra things) but even when I deleted the correct things it didn't work.<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Type in here!"
        />

Answer (score 0):

Add some lines as I have mentioned here.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Type in here!"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:backgroundTint="#ffffffff"
    android:autoText="false"

    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:gravity="top|left
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

Comment: It says "cannot resolve flag" and makes the following text: "android: inputType" red.